# accordion gallery get to first div with mouseleave

Tags: jquery, gallery, accordion, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm doing an image gallery horizontal accordeon. 
On mouseenter the different images show.
How can I add the mouseleave to get back to the first div when I'm not hovering?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){

activeItem = $("#accordion div:first");
$(activeItem).addClass('active');

$("#accordion div.bkgdImg").mouseenter(function(){
$('.tab-content').hide();
$(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
$(this).animate({width: "557px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
activeItem = this;
});

$("#accordion div.bkgdImg").mouseleave(function() { 
$(this).tabs('select', '#accordion div:first');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the solution for later use:

I added again the active class to the div I wanted to show and now when you hover it opens the div you are in and when you leave it makes the first div as active.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

activeItem = $("#accordion div:first");
$(activeItem).addClass('active');

$("#accordion div.bkgdImg").mouseenter(function(){
$('.tab-content').hide();
$(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:500, queue:false});
$(this).animate({width: "557px"}, {duration:500, queue:false});
activeItem = this;
});
$("#accordion div.bkgdImg").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:500, queue:false});
activeItem = $("#accordion div:first");
$(activeItem).addClass('active');
$(activeItem).animate({width: "557px"}, {duration:500, queue:false});
});
$('.sub-tab-trigger').hover(function(){
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('#' + $(this).attr('data-ref')).show()
});         
});
```